# Refactoring to get attributes from self or parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

class `Shop` is potentially a child as it `belongs_to :chain, , optional: true`

The chain has `chain_rules` which apply to the shop if true.

To avoid re-writing patterns for a multiple attributes of both chain and shop, a class method

```
  def shop_rule
    if self.chain_id && self.chain.chain_rules
      self.chain
    else
      self
    end
  end
```

However in the console calling `shop.shop_rule.attribute`, the following error is generated:
`undefined method` shop_rule' for #<Shop: ...`

How should this be defined then?

Comment: You have `def shop_rule` and an error message about `shop_rule` but you claim to be calling the `shop_role` method. What is the actual method name and where is it defined?

Comment: `class Shop`  defines `def shop_role`

Comment: But the error complains about `shop_rule`, not `shop_role`.

Comment: [face palm]. literally could not see that typo.